# R Chi-square test error: 'x' and 'y' must have at least 2 levels

Tags: r, chi-squared

I wonder if there is a way around this error when predictions of only one level has been made:

```
Error in stats::chisq.test(y[1:20], predictions[1:20]) : 
  'x' and 'y' must have at least 2 levels
```

I get it when all predictions are of the same level/class in `chisq.test` (even though the variable has two levels (although both are not present).

Test data:

```
y <- as.factor(c(rep(1, 10), rep(0, 11)))
predictions <- as.factor(c(rep(1, 20), 0))

# Works (with a warning). 
chisq <- stats::chisq.test(y, predictions)

# Does not work due to not having prediction of both factors. 
chisq <- stats::chisq.test(y[1:20], predictions[1:20])
```

(I want to use this in a function; and would prefer if it did not return an error, but rather something more informative)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `chisq.test(table(y[1:20], predictions[1:20]))`. You will see that `X-squared` is `NaN` and `p-value` is `NA`. That's because some expected counts are zeros.

Comment: @DarrenTsai I will remove my answer once the OP confirms it is off-topic

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Fisher's Exact test instead.

```
stats::fisher.test(y, predictions)
```

The "rule of thumb" for a chi-squared test is that it would like to have expected cell counts of 5 or more.  Fisher's exact does not have this restriction and you can use it on any 2x2 table where a chi-squared test would be appropriate.